# Regex not allow numbers

Tags: regex, web-scraping

Playing around with http://www.regexr.com/ trying to get a regex that matches only letters, spaces, and punctuation. For instance, I have a bunch of data that is outlined like so:

```
1. "Ever stop to think, and forget to start again?" - Some Guy
```

and so on. How can I use regex to grab everything but the initial numbers and period?

My regex now is as follow, but seems to grab the numbers:

```
^(\s+|\d+|\w+|[^\d\s\w])+$
```

Comment: What about Unicode letters?

Comment: Not too experienced with regex so I'm not too sure I follow.

Comment: There's a cheatsheet on the site you linked... Use it.

Comment: That's how I got to the answer above.

Comment: Only ASCII letters: `[a-zA-Z]`, punctuation - `[!-,.-/:-@[-\`{-~]`, spaces - `\s`. Combining  - `[a-zA-Z!-,.-\/:-@[-\`{-~\s]+`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4q6P3/1).

Comment: Your regex matches digits because you have `\w` and `\d`. BTW, what should be the final result? Is the tool matching what matches or differently? Please add details to the question.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted, but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the digits and period out of the string:

```js
var str = '1. "Ever stop to think, and forget to start again?" - Some Guy';

console.log(str.replace(/^\d+\. /, ''));
```

The regex, `\d+\.` is looking for:

- At the start of the string: `^`,
- 1 or more numbers: `\d+`,
- Followed by a period: `\.`,
- Followed by a space:

Then it replaces the matched part, `1.`, with an empty string.

Comment: I'm using a scraper that follow JS syntax, but does not allow for anything else besides that.

Comment: @user1721449: Which means you can't use JS?

Comment: Not in the standard way, I only tagged it JS because it uses the syntax from so.

Comment: As in, regex syntax? If the question can't be solved using JS, then don't tag it with JS...

Comment: Sorry just looking for some help; we can't all be perfect.

Comment: I'm not saying we have to be perfect, but I spent time writing this answer, only to find out the language I used isn't usable for you.

Answer (score 0):

With `replace`: `str.replace(/^[0-9. ]+(.*)/, '$1')`.

[Look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is not supported in Javascript, so this cannot be done just with matching (and in languages when it is supported, the pattern "looked behind at" usually cannot have variable length). But you can match something like `".*` or `[ ].*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap your capture group around everything except the start of your line which should include a specific pattern to exclude.. so:

`^\d+\.\s(.*)$`

Using that should specifically on return everything after your space following the digit and period, but only if those are in the